# Aggregate Value in UDF Always Zero, Affecting Local Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

The following UDF returns an integer based on different conditions executed after a query. The variables, `@recCount`, is always a zero despite the fact that it can also be greater than zero. It should contain the value of inline query using `COUNT(*)`.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetConfID] (@eventID      INT,
                                    @conferenceID INT,
                                    @companyID    VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS INT
AS
  BEGIN
      -- Declare the return variable here
      DECLARE @confID INT; -- Conference ID we're passing back

      DECLARE @curAtt INT; -- Current attendance
      DECLARE @maxAtt INT; -- Max attendance
      DECLARE @waitConfID INT; --Waitlist value of current conference
      DECLARE @recCount INT; -- Total number of employees who selected same conference

      SELECT @confID = ec.conferenceID,
             @recCount = (SELECT count(*)
                          FROM   tblRegistration r
                                 INNER JOIN tblRegConferences rc
                                   ON r.ID = rc.regID
                          WHERE  r.optfield2 = @companyID
                                 AND r.eventID = @eventID
                                 AND rc.conferenceID = @conferenceID),
             @curAtt = ec.currentAttendance,
             @maxAtt = ec.maxAttendance,
             @waitConfID = ec.waitListProdID
      FROM   tblEventConferences ec
      WHERE  ec.conferenceID = @conferenceID
             AND ec.isWaitList = 0

      -- If no records were found (waitlist item)
      IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @confID = @conferenceID -- use same value we passed in
        END
      -- records found
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            --Max attendance not reached, return main conference ID
            IF @curAtt < @maxAtt
              BEGIN
                  SET @confID = @conferenceID
              END

            --Max attendance reached, return waitlist ID
            IF @curAtt >= @maxAtt
              BEGIN
                  SET @confID = @waitConfID
              END

            --Company cap reached, return waitlist ID
            IF @recCount > 1
              BEGIN
                  SET @confID = @waitConfID
              END
        END

      RETURN @confID
  END
```

Running it as a query, I get values greater than zero for the field companyCnt, which is `@recCount`'s equivalent.

```
SELECT ec.conferenceID, (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM tblRegistration r
            INNER JOIN tblRegConferences rc ON r.ID = rc.regID
        WHERE
            r.optfield2 = '83b90acc-42af-4de2-9279-76e80eb8b73a'
        AND
            r.eventID = 624
        AND
            rc.conferenceID = 8848
    ) AS companyCnt, ec.currentAttendance, ec.maxAttendance, ec.waitListProdID
    FROM
        tblEventConferences ec
    WHERE
        ec.conferenceID = 8848
    AND
        ec.isWaitList = 0
```

Comment: `select len('83b90acc-42af-4de2-9279-76e80eb8b73a'), cast('83b90acc-42af-4de2-9279-76e80eb8b73a' as varchar(32))`

Comment: As Martin has pointed out, you are truncating your @companyid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change @companyid from varchar(32) to varchar(50).

You are experiencing this problem because the length of company in your query is 36 characters where as the variable is declared only for 32 characters SQL server don't give a warning it just truncates the last characters.